# how to hide Drawer on sidebar menu click React native

Tags: react-native

hi  i want to close drawer on sidebar menu click...

"Drawer code  below which in index.js  file"

```
        `<Drawer ref={(ref) => { this._drawer = ref; }}
```

content={}
onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()}`

"and here is sidebar code   sidebar.js"

Answer (score 0):

If you define ref on drawer as follows:

`<Drawer ref="drawer"`

you can close it using:
`this.refs.drawer.close();`

or as you defined:

`<Drawer ref={(ref) => { this._drawer = ref; }}`

you can close it using:
`this._drawer.close();`

Call it inside your closeDrawer().

Comment: i want to call it from other js file .i.e   Sidebar.js to closeDrawer ()                                              export default class Sidebar extends React.Component 
{
  render()
  {
  return(

Comment: @geekworld: pass your close function as prop to sidebar.js component and call it there using this.props.closeDrawer();

Comment: great...    but i am new to reactnative.....   i don't  know how to pass function as propt.... can you send  code that would be great help

Comment: @geekworld:

bind func. in your component constructor.
this.closeDrawer = this.closeDrawer.bind(this);


then pass it as in component:

<Component
closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer}
...
/>

Comment: hi i used in my projectc .....  i  am  getting error....undefined not object   evaluating this._drawer._root

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for latest versions: Add drawerLockMode property

```
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
{
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    List: { screen: ListScreen }
},
{
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    headerMode: "none",
    drawerLockMode:'locked-closed'
});
```